# d How can I use progress bar while fetching data from database?

Tags: android, database, progress-bar

I'm really bad at googling things I want so I decided to ask here. My question is is it possible to show a progress bar while fetching the data from the database? I'm using the typical code when fetching data(Pass value to php and the php will do the query and pass it again to android)

Edit(I have tried adding proggressdialog but the problem now is the loaded data will appear first before the progress dialog here's my AsyncTask code)

```
 public class getClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public  getClass()
    {
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    }
    URLConnection connection = null;
    String command;
    Context context;
    String ip = new returnIP().getIpAddresss();
    String link = "http://" + ip + "/android/getClass.php";//ip   address/localhost


    public URLConnection getConnection(String link) {
        URL url = null;
        try//retrieves link from string
        {
            url = new URL(link);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        URLConnection connection = null;
        try//opens the url link provided from the "link" variable
        {
            connection = url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        return connection;
    }

    public String getResult(URLConnection connection, String logs) {
        //this is the functions that retrieves what the php file echoes
        //everything that php throws, the phone receives
        String result = "";
        OutputStreamWriter wr = null;
        try {
            wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());//compiles data to be sent to the receiver
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            wr.write(logs);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            wr.flush();//clears the cache-esque thingy of the writer
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        //Read server response

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        result = sb.toString();

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result = "";
        //Toast.makeText(View_Classes.this, "ako n una", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {

            //first data sent is sent in command
            command = (String) arg0[0];//it's in array, because everything you input here is placed in arrays

            //Toast.makeText(View_Classes.this, "andtio n me", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (command == "getCourses") {
                connection = getConnection(link);
                String logs = "";
                logs = "&command=" + URLEncoder.encode(command, "UTF-8");
                logs += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
                result = getResult(connection, logs);


            } else if (command == "getSections") {

                connection = getConnection(link);
                String logs = "";
                logs = "&command=" + URLEncoder.encode(command, "UTF-8");
                logs += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
                logs += "&course=" + URLEncoder.encode(course, "UTF-8");
                result = getResult(connection, logs);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {//this is going to be the next function to be done after the doInBackground function
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase(""))//if there's nothing to return, the text "No records" are going to be thrown
        {

        } else //Array adapter is needed, to be a place holder of values before passing to spinner
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

You can show your progress bar on the preExecute method and then hide it on postExecute. You can do your querying inside the doInBackground method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @torque203 pointed, I would suggest you to check 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...) 
this method was created for that purpose, showing progress to the user.

Answer (score 0):

From developers docs:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
  //show progress bar here
 }

 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     //Pass value to PHP here
     //get values from your PHP
 }



 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    //Here you are ready with your PHP value. Dismiss progress bar here.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onPreExecute() {
   Progress Dialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
}

  public void doInBackground() {
  //do your JSON Coding
 }

public void onPostExecute() {
   Progress Dialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public URLConnection getConnection(String link) {
    URL url = null;
    try//retrieves link from string
    {
        url = new URL(link);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try//opens the url link provided from the "link" variable
    {
        connection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    return connection;
}

public String getResult(URLConnection connection, String logs) {
    //this is the functions that retrieves what the php file echoes
    //everything that php throws, the phone receives
    String result = "";
    OutputStreamWriter wr = null;
    try {
        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());//compiles data to be sent to the receiver
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        wr.write(logs);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        wr.flush();//clears the cache-esque thingy of the writer
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    //Read server response

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    result = sb.toString();

    return result;
}


public class getClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    URLConnection connection = null;
String command;
Context context;
String ip = new returnIP().getIpAddresss();
String link = "http://" + ip + "/android/getClass.php";//ip   address/localhost

}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String result = "";
    //Toast.makeText(View_Classes.this, "ako n una", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {

        //first data sent is sent in command
        command = (String) arg0[0];//it's in array, because everything you input here is placed in arrays

        //Toast.makeText(View_Classes.this, "andtio n me", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (command == "getCourses") {
            connection = getConnection(link);
            String logs = "";
            logs = "&command=" + URLEncoder.encode(command, "UTF-8");
            logs += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            result = getResult(connection, logs);


        } else if (command == "getSections") {

            connection = getConnection(link);
            String logs = "";
            logs = "&command=" + URLEncoder.encode(command, "UTF-8");
            logs += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            logs += "&course=" + URLEncoder.encode(course, "UTF-8");
            result = getResult(connection, logs);
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return result;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {//this is going to be the next function to be done after the doInBackground function
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    if (result.equalsIgnoreCase(""))//if there's nothing to return, the text "No records" are going to be thrown
    {

    } else //Array adapter is needed, to be a place holder of values before passing to spinner
    {

    }
}
```

}